# Why can't I import a default export with "import ... as" with BabelJS

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

In version 5.6.4 of BabelJS, I seemingly cannot "import ... as." Here are examples of what I am trying to do:

In file 'test.js':

```
export default class Test {};
```

In file 'test2.js' (in the same directory):

```
import Test as Test2 from './test';
```

I have also tried to do:

```
import {Test as Test2} from './test';
```

Even though it says nothing about that here:
http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#modules

And only uses brackets in the non-default syntax here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Has anyone done this successfully?

**EDIT**: It is absolutely because of the `default` keyword. So, in this case, the question becomes, does anyone have any links to documentation that states that I should not be able to alias a default import? ECMA or Babel.

Comment: related: [How can I alias a default import in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39282253/1048572)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can import the default export by either

```
import Test2 from './test';
```

or

```
import {default as Test2} from './test';
```

The default export doesn't have `Test` as a name that you would need to alias - you just need to import the default under the name that you want.

The best docs I've found so far is the article [*ECMAScript 6 modules: the final syntax*](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) in Axel Rauschmayers blog.

Comment: Ah default...let me try that.

Comment: That works excellently! Thank you. Dr. Rauschmayers blog, btw, I consider a reliable enough source to be the spec.

Comment: Well you can check out [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-modules) as well, but I think that blog is more readable :-)

Comment: From MDN, it looks like you could also do `import * as Test2`.

Comment: @merlinpatt You have to use `Test2.default` then, though - it's a module namespace object.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the pointing that out. It wasn't clear from the docs. What is the point of allowing that?

Comment: @merlinpatt So that you don't have to declare all names that you want to use. E.g. `import { * as _ } from 'underscore'` will get you the `_` namespace, instead of having to write out all function names.