# How can I alias a default import in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Using ES6 modules, I know I can alias a named import:

```
import { foo as bar } from 'my-module';
```

And I know I can import a default import:

```
import defaultMember from 'my-module';
```

I'd like to alias a default import and I had thought the following would work:

```
import defaultMember as alias from 'my-module';
```

But that results in a parsing (syntax) error.

How can I (or can I?) alias a default import?

Answer (score 1717, accepted):

`defaultMember` already *is* an alias - it doesn't need to be the name of the exported function/thing. Just do

```
import alias from 'my-module';
```

Alternatively you can do

```
import {default as alias} from 'my-module';
```

but that's rather esoteric.

Comment: The alias on its own is esoteric! Importing the named export _and_ the default is handy when testing redux components: `import WrappedComponent, { Component } from 'my-module';`

Comment: some very strict tslinting rules disagree and actually want you to preserve the name of the default input as the filename

Comment: @Blauhirn Is that for old IDEs which cannot follow references and need to use global search-and-replace for their refactoring tools? Ridiculous.

Comment: @Bergi no, it's the tslint rule "import-name", used e.g. by the airbnb tslint rule set and therefore rather widespread. These rules exist to encourage consistent, bugfree and readable code

Comment: MDN docs should reflect these doc updates: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Though it seems handy at first glance, importing the default as a different name but without explicitly stating `alias` should be discouraged. Just like the self increment operator `i++` in most languages, they only become natural when one is familiar enough with the language/framework. These design are counter-intuitive for beginners (think of Roman vs Arabic numerals), and tend to induce more effort in large projects (think of how frequently a programmer explicitly goes to the declaration in a codebase with few explicit type signature and rely on the type system to infer everything).

Comment: @wlnirvana What do you mean by "*without explicitly stating `alias`*"? The alias is *always* explicitly declared. And notice that you cannot import the default under the same name, as `default` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @Bergi I meant something like `import foo from 'my-module';` instead of `import { TheExportedName as foo } from 'my-module';`. IMHO, the latter is better.

Comment: @wlnirvana Sure, but there is no `TheExportedName` for default exports, it's always just the `default`, so the shorthand syntax is unambiguous.

Comment: I found myself defining a constant to rename the default after the import:

`import SuperLongDefaultName from 'le-default`
`const ShortName = SuperLongDefaultName`

I didn't know about `{default as …}` but I want the reader of my code to know at a glance what the original name was. Dunno why, it just would bother me if they didn't.

Comment: @RolandoMurillo There is no "SuperLongDefaultName" of a default export, the only name it has is `default`. You don't need to use `as`, just `import ShortName from 'le-default'`. The module name should be enough to identify the imported value.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm aware of it but I actually do want to respect the name of the default when I'm importing it if that makes sense.

Comment: @RolandoMurillo Again, the default export has no name! Only the module has a name.

Comment: @Bergi, I see what you mean. It's just that when I export a function or a constant, it always has a name. E.g. `export default myFunctionName …`. So, when I import I match that name: `import myFunctionName from …`. And like I said in my first comment -- I know I could just put whatever name I want but I prefer to use the same name as the exported module and rename it in the new file through a constant as needed.

Comment: @RolandoMurillo Oh, you mean the local name. I don't consider that to be important, this is the **encapsulation** that modules are all about! The standard practice is to have that name match the file name / library name anyway, so it would be visible in module specifier of the import declaration. If you *do* consider it important, you probably shouldn't have used a default export in the first place. (Btw, it's possible to export an anonymous function declaration with `export default function(…){…}`).

Comment: Does this only works when default export is in index.html or any file ?

Comment: @Bergi can you link to official documentation of this explanation, I didn't find any

Comment: @vikramvi There's is no "official" documentation (the only *official* document is the specification itself), but most things are documented at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Answer (score 46):

## Origins, Solution and Answer:

### Background:

A **module** can export functionality or objects from itself for the use in other modules

The Modules Used for:

- Code reuse
- Separation of functionalities
- Modularity

### What are Import Aliases?

Import aliases are where you take your standard import, but instead of using a pre-defined name by the exporting module, you use a name that is defined in the importing module.

### Why is this important?

You may be importing multiple exported modules but the names of the exports (from different modules) are the same, this confuses JS.
Aliases solve this.

**Example of Multiple Alias Failed Compilation:**

```
Failed to compile.
/somepath/index.js
SyntaxError: /somepath/index.js: Identifier 'Card' has already been declared (6:9)
```

> Importing Aliases will allow you to import similarly named exports to
> your module.

```
import { Button } from '../components/button'
import { Card } from '../components/card'
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements'
```

**When importing named exports (not default):**

```
// my-module.js

function functionName(){
  console.log('Do magic!');
}

export { functionName );
```

**Import in module:**

```
import { functionName as AliasFunction} from "my-module.js"
```

### What is [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#using_the_default_export)?

Default export allows us to export a single value or to have a fallback value for your module.

**For importing default exports:**

```
// my-module.js
function functionName(){
  console.log('Do magic!');
}

export default functionName;
```

## Solution

The `defaultMember` mentioned in the question is an alias already, you can change the name to whatever you will like.

### Now import the exported function (`functionName()`);

```
import AliasFunction from "my-module.js"
```

**Or like this (as mentioned by @Bergi):**

```
import {default as AliasFunction} from 'my-module.js';
```