# typescript import module as variable not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to import a variable from another file using and giving alias name for that but typescript throwing error alias name not defined.

Ex:

`import { headerItems as TestHeader } from './headers';`

```
Typescript version: 3.2.4
Ng cli: 7.3.7
webpack: 4.19.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use: import { headerItems } from './headers'; and create instance in the constructor

Comment: @PrashantPimpale that is working. my question is why alias name is not working.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_an_export_with_a_more_convenient_alias Is it related to typescript or webpack?

Comment: Might be this will help:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39282290/7124761

Comment: @niko yes its part of js. but in angular typescript will compile the code if i am not wrong

Comment: @PrashantPimpale thanks for link. my question is regarding for that only which was working previous of typescript. after upgrading into angular 7 then started facing issue.

Comment: can you downgrade to 3.1.x and see if that error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13212
and https://github.com/IgorMinar/angular/commit/b7313ac2c619e96617258606d090f42ad73c44c0

> It's unclear why `import as` results in the aliases to be undefined.
>
> Plain tsc seems to do the right thing and emits the correct code, so
>   it might be some kind of interaction in @angular/cli or webpack that
>   are causing the failure.
>
> This should be investigated separately from the tsc update in
>   angular/angular. See angular/angular-cli#13212

-- Igor Minar