# Mutable difference between ES6 named and default exports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

When importing/exporting data from ES6 modules, mutability of that data appears to be different between named imports and exports. Is there a reason for this or some fundamental difference I'm not understanding?

```
// counter.js
export let count = 0;

export const incrementCount = () => count += 1;

export default count;
```

```
// main-default.js
import count, { incrementCount } from './counter';

console.log(count); // 0

incrementCount();
incrementCount();

console.log(count); // 0
```

```
// main-named.js
import { count, incrementCount } from './counter';

console.log(count); // 0

incrementCount();
incrementCount();

console.log(count); // 2
```

In both scenarios, I would expect `count` to increment. However, this only happens when using named exports.

Comment: For what it's worth, code above was tested after being transpiled with Babel 7.6.0.

Comment: does the same thing happen without transpiling?

Comment: @JohnnyCrain if you watch out the transpiled code carefully, the function changes the name export not the default exported count

Comment: @dandavis The result is the same whether transpiled or run directly by Chromium.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It is because count is number not object. By importing default you are assigning value of count to new variable. By named import you have readonly copy like object.
Consider this:

```
// counter.js
export let count = {a:0};
export const incrementCount = () => count.a += 1;
export default (function(){ return count.a})();
```

When you run:

```
// main-default.js
import countdefault, { count, incrementCount } from './counter.mjs';
console.log(countdefault, count);
incrementCount();
incrementCount();
console.log(countdefault, count);
```

you get:

0 { a: 0 }

0 { a: 2 }

but when you change counter export to object:

```
// counter.js
export let count = {a:0};
export const incrementCount = () => count.a += 1;
export default (function(){ return count})();
```

you get:

{ a: 0 } { a: 0 }

{ a: 2 } { a: 2 }

Comment: This is wrong. An import can still be an alias, it has nothing to do with the value being an object or not.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you used `export default count;`, which does not export the `count` binding (allowing aliasing the mutable variable by an import) but actually creates a new, hidden variable that gets the initial value assigned but is never changed afterwards.

```
export default count;
```

desugars to

```
let *default* = count; // where *default* is a guaranteed collision-free identifier
export { *default* as default }
```

What you want instead is

```
// counter.js
let count = 0;
export const incrementCount = () => count += 1;
export { count as default }
```

```
// main-default.js
import countA, { default as countB, incrementCount } from './counter';

console.log(countA, countB); // 0, 0
incrementCount();
console.log(countA, countB); // 1, 1
```

See also [How can I alias a default import in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39282253/1048572).