# How to retain 'live binding' with default export

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

As you may know, in ECMAScript modules exports create a so called *live view* on a given variable. For example, when we change an exported variable some time later in the code, the change will be visible in modules that import it:

```
export let x = 1;
x = 2;

-----------

import { x } from "./x.mjs";
console.log(x) // logs 2
```

But things are a bit different with a `default` export. A `default` export is associated with a particular value, not a variable name. So when we do:

```
let x = 1;
export default x;
x = 2;

---------------------

import x from "./x.mjs";
console.log(x) // logs 1
```

We get the old value.

How to make `default` export behave like named export, that is, how to enforce it to be a live view on a given variable?

Playground: [glitch.com](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/live-view-on-defalut-export?path=public%2Fx.mjs%3A1%3A0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize a shared javascript module default export](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65541254/1048572) or [Mutable difference between ES6 named and default exports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58437520/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do it:

```js
// x.mjs
let x = 1;
export { x as default }; // this is important to export actual live binding
x = 2;
```

And then on the other side:

```js
// script.mjs
import test from "./x.mjs";
console.log(test) // will log 2
```

Another way to do it is with closure, but it will require wrapping of your variable export into a function:

```js
// x.mjs
let x = 1;
export default () => x;
x = 2;
```

```js
// script.mjs
import { default as _default } from "./x.mjs";
console.log(_default()) // will log 2
```