# How to change default component name while importing in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-component

I want to import a component named "Create" while importing I want to change its name. But I cannot change the component name as I export the "Create" component as default.

```
import Create as CreateCustomer from 'sales_app/src/screen/customer/Create' ;
```

I am new to react-native. Need Help.

Comment: refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282253/how-can-i-alias-a-default-import-in-javascript

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can rename default import like this

```js
  import { default as CreateCustomer } from 'sales_app/src/screen/customer/Create';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, I got my answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282253/how-can-i-alias-a-default-import-in-javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
import CreateCustomer from 'sales_app/src/screen/customer/Create';
```

Answer (score 0):

**problem can be solved as below,**

In the file we need to export, we can avoid **"default export"** and do a custom export and import in the custom name.

for example, if you need to get **Button** as **MyButton**

in the  button file, we can export it as,
`export {Button as MyButton};`

and as usual we can import it as `import {MyButton} from './another-file';`