# File import not initializing in constructor ionic native. The cordova file plugin and javascript file interface is conflicting .?

Tags: file, cordova, ionic5

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
```

I can’t use the class File from cordova-plugin-file in my application cause there is another interface from JavaScript also called File.

This name conflict impedes my app to access the cordova-plugin-file functions I want.

File from JavaScript has this description : “
interface File
Provides information about files and allows JavaScript in a web page to access their content.”.

File from cordova-plugin-file should (alias) const File: FileOriginal
import File
'File' is declared but its value is never read

Here is my code :

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
export class Tab1Page {
constructor(public file: File) {}
...
}
```

Comment: If i got you right you have naming collision during import. To resolve this you can import using alias https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282253/how-can-i-alias-a-default-import-in-javascript.

Comment: thanks mate, you guided me in the right direction. Issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that it helps someone. Workaround was to declare cordova-plugin-file outside constructor.

```
import { File as cordova_file } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
private file: typeof cordova_file
constructor(
```

Comment: Hi, using your solution I always have the file object undefined. Could you please help? I posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71727472/file-import-not-initializing-in-constructor-ionic-native-the-cordova-file-plugi

Comment: I am not pretty sure on this. Check if you're android ask storage permission at app launch.  Its required.

Comment: If you get the file object undefined then it is because you must invoke the new to construct the object.   Example:  private file: cordova_file = new cordova_file();